# Complex objetcs with SOAP webservice: ClassCastException

Tags: android, web-services, soap, classcastexception

I'm getting ArrayList of complex objects using KSOAP2 library based on [this](http://roderickbarnes.com/blog/droid-chronicles-web-services-handling-complex-parameters) tutorial:

And I'm able to receive arrayList of objects. The problem is when the envelope have just one object... When I do:

```
//...Call webservice
Vector<SoapObject> vectorOfSoapObject = (Vector<SoapObject>)envelope.getResponse();
//pass Vector to ArrayList
```

It returns me an `ClassCastException` on this line, when I have just one object on the envelope. When I have more it works fine (I made debug to see this happening)...

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem. Using the suggestion of @Pranalee, I made this:

```
//call webservice
Object o1 = envelope.getResponse();
if(o1 == null){//no devices updated
    Log.d("GetUpdatesThread","o1==null");
} else if(o1.getClass().toString().equals(new SoapObject("", "").getClass().toString())){//one device updated
    Log.d("GetUpdatesThread","class -- soapObject");
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    Device d = convertToDevice(result);
    devicesUpdated.add(d);
} else if (o1.getClass().toString().equals(new Vector().getClass().toString())){//more than one device updated
    Log.d("GetUpdatesThread","class -- vector");
    Vector<SoapObject> vectorOfSoapObject2 = (Vector<SoapObject>)envelope.getResponse();
    for (SoapObject soapObject : vectorOfSoapObject2) {
         Device d = convertToDevice(soapObject);
         devicesUpdated.add(d);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Is `convertToDevice` a custom method you wrote to parse the `SoapObject` to and fill the `Device`?

Answer (score 1):

It could be case that when there are more than one records, service returns `Vector<SoapObject>` and when there is only record, it is returning only `SoapObject`. 
You are trying to cast `SoapObject` to `Vector<SoapObject>`, so the `ClassCastException`. 
This is the issue with implementaton of service. However to fix this at your end , you should first get `envelope.getResponse()` as `Object`, and check if `Object` is instance of `Vector<SoapObject>` or `SoapObject` before casting.

```
Vector<SoapObject> vectorOfSoapObject = null;
Object response = envelope.getResponse();

if( response instanceof Vector){
   Vector<SoapObject> vectorOfSoapObject = (Vector<SoapObject>) response;       
}else if(response instanceof  SoapObject){
    //cast single object
   SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) response;
   //initialize vector
   vectorOfSoapObject = new Vector<SoapObject>();
   //add single object to vector. 
   vectorOfSoapObject.add(soapObject);
}
```

this way u wont have to change other code which u might have written under the assumption that u'll get list always

Comment: Hi! And how can I check if is an instance of `Vector<SoapObject>` or `SoapObject`?

Comment: using instanceof of operator. Have updated answer with code snippet